# return quoted string arg for every occurence of a specified function

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, g++, std

I am using Ubuntu Linux 14.04 and g++ 4.9.2 in C++11x mode and trying to use
std::regex (I could also use boost regex).

This string needs to be parsed (removed the escapes on quotes for clarity):

"`(1+MyFun("foo" )-"3" ) > (MyFun ("x2_1:3")+MyFun( "10.0.0.30:80/b3.new" ) - MyFun2("z:2")/OldMyFun("blue")`"

Notice the requirement to allow various spacing and to avoid a partial match of MyFun (e.g. do not match OldMyFun("blue").

I need to return the **unquoted** arg to every occurrence of MyFun in the string, ***without*** MyFun. For the above example:

- foo
- x2_1:3
- 10.0.0.30:80/b3.new

But none of these:

- 1
- 3
- z:2
- blue

I have this regex, but it returns the MyFun along with the desired (and quoted) args:

```
const std::string regexString="(MyFun\\()+(\"([^\"]*)\")\\)";
```

But need only the unquoted arg. I am using std::regex and std::sregex_iterators.

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    const std::string str="(1+MyFun(\"foo\" )-\"3\" ) > (MyFun (\"x2_1:3\")"
        "+MyFun( \"10.0.0.30:80/b3.new\" ) - MyFun2(\"z:2\")/OldMyFun(\"blue\")";
    const std::string regexString="MyFun\\s*\\(\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*\\)";
    try
    {
        std::regex rgx(regexString);
        std::sregex_iterator i(str.begin(), str.end(), rgx);
        std::sregex_iterator e;
        while (i != e)
        {
            std::cout<<i->str()<<std::endl;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr<<e.what()<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: use this `"(?:MyFun\\()+\"([^\"]*)\"\\)"` and then print the group index 1.

Comment: I tried this in my test program but got zero output.

Answer (score 0):

```
MyFun\s*\(\s*"([^"]+)"\s*\)
```

or

```
MyFun\\s*\\(\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"\\s*\\)
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group 1.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/8

Comment: this returns the MyFun as part of the answer, but only the arg must be returned.

Comment: @user2138025 grab `group 1`

Comment: I tried \\1 in my test program but it returns nothing.

Comment: @user2138025 try '$1'

Comment: I dont think is the proper c++11x std::regex syntax. Could try your suggestion in the code snippet above?